# How to increase write speed with USB High speed host mode with STM32F4?

Tags: stm32f4, usb-host

I want to write into a text file in a Flash drive using STM32F407 (XCore407I Core Board) and via USB HS mode. I have used fatfs library and also [Tilen Majerle](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/08/library-29-usb-msc-host-usb-flash-drive-stm32f4xx-devices/) Libraries for USB HS HOST mode. I succeeded to write to a text file in a 8GB flash memory. But I have two problems here:

1. When I use another flash drive except 8GB, for example 16GB one, it can't write to flash and an error occurs in mounting stage.
2. Maximum speed that I have reached is 1.3MB/s. I want to increase this speed, how can I do this? Does anybody have  any document for using USB HS in STM32?

Comment: This questions is far too broad, and almost entirely missing detail about what you have tried; also the error situation is almost a distinct issue.  One thing you should definitely do though is make sure you are writing data in appropriately sized buffer chunks.  Also, you should compare the performance of the specific flash drive in a PC, making sure that you are seeing actual write performance and not just operating system buffering.

Comment: Also please confirm that you are using an external PHY as the on-chip one does not support high speed mode: "When using
the USB OTG HS in HS mode, an external PHY device connected to the ULPI is required."   Also compare what sort of read performance you can achieve, even if you read empty blocks and throw the data away.  This may help indicate if you have a flash (or write size) issue vs. a USB (or usb transfer size) issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with USB so I used an example code to do what I want. Also I modified write buffer data and I reach this speed. I use a STM32F405 discovery that contains a ULPI. Do anything else is needed to achieve high speed functionality?

Comment: This problem needs a systematic debug. First, does your board connect to your PC host as HS device?

Answer (score 1):

The library linked in your question *does not support* USB High Speed mode.

Rather, it supports use of the on-chip High Speed OTG *peripheral* in **Full Speed** mode.

```
Supported USB FS and USB HS in FS mode
  USB OTG is connected to USB FS mode on STM32F4-Discovery board
  USB OTG is connected to USB HS in FS mode on STM32F429-Discovery board
```

Some "reading of the fine print" is necessary to see this in the above - specifically that `HS` is mentioned only when followed by `in FS mode`.  And in fact the word "high" appears nowhere on the main page of your link.

It's also quite logical why this is the case: the *hardware* will not support high speed operation without the use of an external PHY chip connected to the processor's ULPI pins.  The wiring connections given in the documentation of the software library are specifically for connection to one of the on-chip full speed PHYs.

The STM32F4DISCOVERY (which actually has an 'F407 not an 'F405) does not contain a high speed PHY.  It breaks out the ULPI pins, but you would have to provide a carrier board containing the PHY chip.  (Also note that on this board the software is using the full speed peripheral engine - only on the `F429 does it use the high speed peripheral, *but still in full speed mode*).

Its likely that trying to add a PHY is not going to be a wise choice to achieving your ultimate goal, especially as there would be a lot of software work to be done.  You may want to try switching to another MCU (though high speed PHYs are more commonly found on SoCs than MCUs), and perhaps do some research on comparative performance that might be achieved with one able to operate a high performance SD card in native (rather than low performance SPI) mode.  In reality though, any path to achieving high speed logging other than buying a proven hardware + operating system solution is likely going to be a lengthy and challenging technical undertaking.

Comment: I'm sorry. I use XCore407I board (this link: https://www.waveshare.com/XCore407I.htm). it is said that it has USB3300 USB HS PHY. So do another hardware is needed?

Comment: You should have accurately stated that to begin with, instead of **falsely** stating that you were using a discovery board.  But it doesn't change the fact that **the library you are using does not support high speed mode**.  You would need different software, a topic far too broad for an SE question.

Comment: You are right. It was my fault not being accurate. But if the software is not for USB HS is it possible to achieve 1.3Mb/s speed with USB FS?! As I know the maximum speed in USB FS is 1.5MB/s! Also I achieved speed of 2.5MB/s when data size to be written to flash was below 100MB! But above 100MB, speed decreases to 1.3MB/s.

Comment: That's most likely measurement error.  At the outside of unlikelihood, it's perhaps possible that the hardware is somehow operating in high speed mode on its own (though I would **extremely** doubt this could happen without at least some configuration bit settings in the USB and GPIO alternate function registers - in fact how are you even using the ULPI without modifying the software?) but the software is still using full speed sized transfer payloads which cannot take full advantage of the high speed bus.  **Fundamentally the issue here is that you are using the wrong software for the job.**

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are not starting with the demonstration software package provided for your board? One of the demos does what you are asking for. See the 'Demo' link on https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/XCore407I

Page 14 of the XCor407l user manual (available on the same Web page), in section 2.9.5, states: 'HS USB demo, the development board works as USB host; USB flash drive demo'. This appears to be exactly what you want as a starting point.

You can download the software, including source code, from the 'Demo' link. The source code for this example is in 'EVK407L-Demo/USB HS Examples/Project/USB_Host_Examples/MSC'. I took a quick look at the source code, it clearly supports the ULPI.

As I recall, from having written firmware for several USB high-speed devices, the key technical issues operating at high speed are:

High-speed transceiver: For a USB device to connect at high speed (480M bits/s), a handshake is needed, and the devices turn on their high-speed transceivers. If you look at the Microchip USB3300 datasheet, you will see on page 20 that the 'Function Control' register defaults to the value 0x41, so the full-speed transceiver is enabled (section 6.1.4.5, XcvrSelect[1:0] has the value 1). The firmware that controls the ULPI must walk it through correctly turning on the high-speed transceiver.

Packet size: In USB 2.0 high speed mode, the data transfer packet size is 512 bytes, as opposed to 64 bytes in USB 1.1 full speed mode. This applies only to USB data transfer, not to USB commands and responses. The firmware must take this packet size into account when reading and writing data.

Regarding the data transfer speed, you are doing well to achieve 1.3M Bytes/s with USB 1.1 full speed. There is overhead in the protocol, the host and device exchange commands and status in addition to the data, and that takes time.

The USB 2 specifications may be helpful. They are well-written, and available at USB.org, see http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/#usb20spec